# Swift SpriteKit: How to generate objects and make the game view move upwards as my player moves up the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im creating a game sort of like Doodle Jump where my player bounces off objects and moves upwards while scoring points.

How do I make the Y-axis move up infinitely and generate the same object, but in random positions as my player moves up?

I don't have any code for this, because I really need some parameters on how to do it and I'm a little new to this.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make the objects move down the screen, and generate new objects from the top that also move down.

Comment: Yea, I think thats what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, lets call it `Bar`.

```
class Bar: SKSpriteNode {
     init(position p: CGPoint){
        super.init(texture: nil, color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 30))
        position = p
        name = "bar"
     }
}
```

At the begin you can use `arc4random_uniform()` to generate x and y coordinates  at which you place a bar element. (in your scene’s initializer)

```
class Scene: SKScene {

   init(size: CGSize){
       super.init(size: size)
       placeBarAtRandomPositions();
   }

   func randomPoint(scene: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
      let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(scene.width)))
      let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(scene.height))) 
      return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
   }


}
```

You make the Y-axis infinitely by moving the bars down. You move down the bars for instance when the player is moving up. If a Bar moves out of the scene at the bottom you generate a new random position at the top where you insert a new Bar.  Example:

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
   enumerateChildNodesWithName("bar") { (node, _) -> () in
      if(node.position.y < -node.size.height/2){ //Because a node’s origin is the center
          node.remove()
          self.spawnBarNodeAtTop()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you type this out in code so I have something to reference? Sorry, this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Which part don’t you understand exactly?

Comment: I’ve added some snippets to illustrate what I mean. ***This code may not work but I am sure you will be able to make it work if you try.*** If you don’t

Comment: Thank you! Would i create a separate .swift folder or put this all of this in my GameScene?

Comment: It is good practice to make a Swift file for every class. So yes, create separate .swift files.

Comment: @RaeTucker You’re welcome! I added a `randomPoint` example because that maybe the hardest if you are new to Swift.